# Access Denied error on running athena query from root account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I am getting an access denied error when I try to run `athena` query from root account. what am I doing wrong?

I have tried to create `IAM user roles`, but not sure if I am doing right. I just wanted to do a quick test.

Create s3 bucket -> upload csv -> go to athena -> pull data from s3 -> run query

Error that I am getting is:

> Your query has the following error(s):
>
> Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: BF8CDA860116C79B; S3 Extended Request ID: 825bTOZNiWP1bUJUGV3Bg5NSzy3ywqZdoBtwYItrxQfr8kqDpGP1RBIHR6NFIBySgO/qIKA8/Cw=)

This query ran against the `"sampledb"` database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum or contact customer support with

```
Query Id: c08c11e6-e049-46f1-a671-0746da7e7c84.
```

What am I doing wrong. I just wanted to do a quick test

Comment: Athena does not have access to your S3.

Comment: how do I give access ?

Comment: is there a step by step tutorial somewhere ?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/access-denied-athena/

Answer (score 0):

If executing query from AWS Athena Web console, Ensure you have access to S3 bucket location of table.you can extract location from `SHOW CREATE TABLE` command.